# How to get Pdf url from webView in android studio

Tags: java, android, webview

I have faced some problems in WebView in android studio.

I want to get a pdf URL from a website. if I click on any link on the website, It opened that page in WebView, and I got a URL of that link but when I click on the pdf link it didn't work and I didn't get the URL of pdf in WebView.

Please help me to solve this problem.

this is my webview code:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;
TextView title;
ActivityWebViewBinding binding;
String data;
Dialog dialog;


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityWebViewBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
 
    webView = binding.webView;
    title = binding.title;
    binding.backIcon.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
    data = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.getLoadsImagesAutomatically();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);


    /* if website doesn't open proper way then we put this code in webView*/

    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    /* if website doesn't open proper way then we put this code in webview*/


    webView.setDownloadListener((url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength) -> {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "myPDFile.pdf");
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
    });


    dialog = CommonMethod.getDialog(this);
    dialog.show();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Processing webView url click...");
            String googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";
            Log.d("url",url);
            if (URLUtil.isFileUrl(url)) {
                view.loadUrl(googleDocs + url);
            } else {

                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            Log.e("TAG", "Error: " + description);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
           
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl(data);
    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem? shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called for me neither